# ErrorIconDrawable in TextInputLayout does not show anything

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am trying to set an icon in `textInputLayout` error like this :

[image]

I set this `app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/login_erroricon"` in TextInputLayout but when i run app it does not show anything.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_login_email"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_login_emailLabel"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/email_icon"
    app:startIconTint="@color/white"
    app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/login_erroricon">
```

I also try it in the code but it does not appear anything :

```
 textInputLayout_login_email.errorIconDrawable=resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.login_erroricon)
```

**Attention : text is ok but icon is disappear.**

Comment: The error icon is on the right. Check the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#adding-errors-to-a-text-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the material.io documents states a TextInputLayout contains:

[image]

1. Container
2. Leading icon
3. Label
4. Input text
5. Trailing icon
6. Activation indicator
7. Helper/error/counter text
8. Prefix/suffix/placeholder (not shown)

**There is no icon for Helper/Error/Counter Text**, It only exists for Right side of the container (5)

What you want to achieve can be a **custom** implementation.

Add a TextView with drawableStart attribute under your TextInputLayout.